# Android Studio 2.2.1 NDK Error:Cannot get property 'soFolder' on null object

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I tried to link my existing NDK C code with the new Android Studio 2.2.1 from the relevant **Link C++ Project with Gradle** menu but I'm getting the following error:

**Error:Cannot get property 'soFolder' on null object**

I really have no idea what is causing this error as my native code used to work fine in previous Android Studio versions.

Currently my app-specific gradle file looks like this

[image: gradle file]

In addition here are my mk files:

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/android-config.mk
LOCAL_CFLAGS :=  -DNO_WINDOWS_BRAINDEATH -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_AS 
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm) 
    LOCAL_CFLAGS :=$(LOCAL_CFLAGS) -march=armv6 
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sha/sha1-armv4-large.S 
endif 
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),x86) 
    LOCAL_CFLAGS :=$(LOCAL_CFLAGS) -msse2 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom 
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sha/sha1-586.S
endif 
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),mips) 
    LOCAL_CFLAGS :=$(LOCAL_CFLAGS) -march=mips1
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sha/sha1-mips.S
endif 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES) \
    sha/sha1dgst.c \
    nativecalc.c \
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includeLocal
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE:= nativecalc
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

android-config.mk

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN #-DTERMIO
# From DEPFLAG=
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_NO_CAMELLIA -DOPENSSL_NO_CAPIENG -DOPENSSL_NO_CAST -DOPENSSL_NO_CMS -DOPENSSL_NO_GMP -DOPENSSL_NO_IDEA -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_MDC2 -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_SHA0 -DOPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 -DOPENSSL_NO_SEED -DOPENSSL_NO_STORE -DOPENSSL_NO_WHIRLPOOL
# Extra
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_NO_HW -DOPENSSL_NO_ENGINE -DZLIB
# Debug
# LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DCIPHER_DEBUG
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi x86 mips
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

Any ideas how can I fix this in order for my native code to compile successfully?